# How to make gradle docker plugin dependsOn on a task

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle with docker plugin (com.palantir.docker) for building a docker image.
This work well but i want to add a task as a `dependsOn`. This task create file needed in my container.

I've tried to do that :

```
docker {
    dependsOn("otherSubModule:otherTask")
    name "image_name:${version}"
    copySpec.with {
        from("build/libs") {
            into("build/libs")
        }
        from("filePath/") {
            into("dist")
        }
    }
}
```

But it seem that the action dependsOn doesn't exist in the closure docker.
How can i have the same result with this plugin ?
And I want if this is a possibility to keep the same command grom lauching this build
`gradle docker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to have the `docker` task depend on `otherSubModule:otherTask`, you should be able to write the following:

```
tasks.docker.dependsOn('otherSubModule:otherTask')
```

What you have tried doesn’t seem to work as `docker` is also the name of an extension.

Comment: Yes docker is not a task. But i wonder if their is a possiblity to link it as a task

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly … Have you already tried my suggestion?

Comment: I just try it and its work thanks. I didn't know this way of linking  task